# How to organize update script across versions

Tags: git

I'm looking for good practices to deal with scripts in Git that are necessary only for one version of the application.

Let's say in version v1.0 I have:

```
install/install.sh
install/alter_tableA.sql
```

`alter_tableA.sql` will be used during the installation to add a column or whatever is necessary.

In version v2.0 I have:

```
install/install.sh
install/alter_tableB.sql
```

`alter_tableB.sql` is necessary for v2.0, and I don't need `alter_tableA.sql` anymore.

How to organize this in order to know easily what `alter_xxx.sql` has been done for a specific version?

Should I add a folder:

```
install/install.sh
install/v1.0/alter_tableA.sql
install/v2.0/alter_tableB.sql
```

This allows to see easily what has been done for a specific version. But then, when merging into the master branch:

1. Do I keep all folders,
2. or should I keep only the last version and rely on tags to find the folder for the previous version?

The first option allows me to have eveything available immediately, but can become a mess with the number of versions increasing.
The second one seems more clean, but I lose examples of script that could be reused in future version, unless I know it has been done and I look for it specifically in tags.

Which is the best good practice? Or should a completely different structure?
The folder in my project is currently a mess, so I'm open to any good idea.

Comment: The way Laravel does it is to have a migration table which tracks which of the migrations have been run. So you would just provide migrations for every change and look in the migrations table which ones to skip. Successfully ran migrations are added to the migrations table. Even a change to the migrations table can be part of a migration. Rather nice how it works there. This is less of a git thing though.

Comment: My organization uses the first approach of subfolders for each version, and they keep them all. I'm not at all sure whether it's a best practice, but there's a data point for you at least.